# Php: How to convert a datetime string to UNIX time

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, unix-timestamp

I have a datetime string with format:

```
2015-03-02T04:46:48+01:00
```

and I need to convert it to UNIX time(integer type)(Almost all research result are about convert UNIX-time to datetime-string, so sad). Please help. Thanks all!

Comment: Next time try your question title with google first: **https://www.google.com/search?q=Php%3A+How+to+convert+a+datetime+string+to+UNIX+time&hl=en** This has been answered like a million times all over the web. And if you were really looking for a CakePHP solution, then you should start with  the Cookbook: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::fromString**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strtotime :

```
 echo strtotime('2015-03-02T04:46:48+01:00');
```

Will return :

```
1456890408
```